# Chrome does not allow certificate chained with self-signed certificate

Tags: google-chrome, security, ssl, certificate, tls1.2

I have certificate, which chained with self-signed certificate. Chrome refuses it, I can't even click > Advanced > proceed.
If I put directly the self-signed certificate, Chrome gives warning, but still allows to enter the site.

Firefox - working. It is in new versions of chrome.

Is it known issue, or feature?

Comment: Is this happening for an application being accessed using *localhost*?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Solved by removing extendedKeyUsage from CA certificate

Answer (score 0):

This flag seems to be overriding the config: --ignore-certificate-errors